# Why am I getting an infinite loop when printing the location that core location returns back to console?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

Working through the big nerd ranch ios programming book and running into issues now and again because the book was based on coding for ios6 and I'm using the latest version of XCode/ios7.

Anyway currently working with the Core Location framework and have added it to my targets list. Currently trying to get the location of device with simulated location as UK London. Here is my code which sometimes works and sometimes throws an error if it can't get a location.

**.h interface file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}

@end
```

**.m implementation file:**

```
#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@interface WhereamiViewController ()

@end

@implementation WhereamiViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self){
        //create location manager object
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        //there will be a warning from this line of code
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        //and we want it to be as accurate as possible
        //regardless of how much time/power it takes
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        //tell our manager to start looking for its location immediately
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}


@end
```

**Console logs:**

```
2013-10-13 19:21:43.546 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/13/13, 7:21:43 PM British Summer Time
2013-10-13 19:21:44.545 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/13/13, 7:21:44 PM British Summer Time
2013-10-13 19:21:45.546 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/13/13, 7:21:45 PM British Summer Time
2013-10-13 19:21:46.546 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/13/13, 7:21:46 PM British Summer Time
2013-10-13 19:21:47.547 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/13/13, 7:21:47 PM British Summer Time
2013-10-13 19:21:48.548 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/13/13, 7:21:48 PM British Summer Time
2013-10-13 19:21:48.925 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/13/13, 7:21:48 PM British Summer Time
2013-10-13 19:21:49.926 Whereami[44554:v4b] <+57.74753400,-134.45332304> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @
```

As you can see there is an infinite loop. What would be the best way to deal with this situation? I'm still learning and don't want to complicate things. I'd like to keep at the pace I'm going with the book. I do understand that these little issue I'm running into can be beneficial to my learning. Trying to understand newer ways of doing older things has made me realise I sometimes have to go back to the old way and fully understand it before doing it the new way.

Help will be appreciated
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an infinite loop.  locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation is a delegate method called by the location manager regularly to update your WhereamiViewController with the phone's new location.

In the line

```
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
```

you've told the locationManager to call delegate methods of the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol on your view controller.  The warning caused by that line can be avoided by replacing

```
@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController
```

in your .h file with

```
@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

which tells the compiler that WhereamIViewController adheres to the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol. You should note that the delegate method locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation is deprecated in iOS6 and you should instead use locationManager:didUpdateLocations.  The CLLocationManagerDelegate documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html).

You can use

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

to stop receiving location updates through the delegate methods or

```
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
```

to allow the location manager to pause updates when the location data is unlikely to change.

For more information on the situation, the understanding of which is fundamental to Objective-C programming, you should read into [Objective-C Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

Comment: Things are starting to make sense now. The book mentioned "Call backs" then I read the more about protocols and because I've much experience in javascript/jquery it made it a lot easier to understand what was going on. It was the delegate stuff that confused me at first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an infinite loop, it's just how `CLLocationManager` works. It's calling your delegate method in intervals. I think that property [`distanceFilter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter) on `CLLocationManager` might be what you're looking for.

Also, you should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`, as `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error. It is how it works.  And you should use

> locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

instead of

> locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

[which is Deprecated in iOS 6.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateToLocation%3afromLocation%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Its not a infinite loop its just that the location manager calls its delegate a lot when you use best precession. Either stop the checking after you get a hit or use less precision(i think that will reduce the amount of calls).

Answer (score 0):

It's not an infinite loop. You asked for constant location updates, and that's what you are getting. If you look at the timestamps on your location updates they are about 1 second apart.

An infinite loop is code that runs without ever doing anything else:

```
while (TRUE)
{
   NSLog(@"Log statement);
}
```

That code is a true infinite loop and would hang your program and cause the system to kill it due to inactivity.

If you specify a non-zero distanceFilter of at least a few meters (try 10 to start) you will cut down a great deal on the "chatter" you get from the location manager. That will cause it to only send you a notification when it detects a movement of at least the specified distance.